# Не запускается команда javac

Tags: java, javac

подскажите, делаю запуск через такую запись:

```
C:\Users\user>javac Example.java
```

Выходит ошибка:

> javac: file not found: Example.java
>   Usage: javac   use -help for a list of possible options

когда прописываю путь полностью `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\bin\javac" "C:\Java\Example.java"`, то класс создается.
как исправить эту ошибку, чтобы класс создавался через команду javac?

Comment: Когда вы выполняете команду `javac Example.java`, компилятор ищет файл Example.java в том же каталоге, где вы выполняете команду. В вашем случае - это `C:\Users\user`. А файл у вас лежит в `C:\Java`. Так что стоит перейти в каталог `C:\Java` и всё будет работать.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно прописать путь к javac в системном окружении.
Тогда система будет знать, где находится исполняемый файл javac.Как записать системную переменную PATH в различных системах можно посмотреть тут: https://www.java.com/ru/download/help/path.xml

Comment: Неа, javac ведь прекрасно запускается и пишет ошибку про ненайденный файл с кодом программы

Comment: Если javac запускается нормально и не найден только путь к вашему файлу, то перейдите в каталог вашего файла и запускайте из него. Если у вас система Windows, то введите команду "cd путь/к/вашему файлу". Только затем "javac Example.java"